# Kids animated show with a magic globes and a fan

Tags: story-identification

Around 1995-1996 I watched a TV show about a family, parents with two kids, a boy, and a girl.
In the show, their grandmother had a magic globe, and with a fan, she touched the globe at some point, and then the family was teleported to that spot on earth where they traveled.

Comment: https://13thstreetpromotions.com/tag/author/

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for the answer, but that show aired much earlier might be even in the late '80s.

Comment: I was just getting it out of the way :-)

Comment: Was it animated? Live action? Do you remember the country you watched it or the network?

Comment: @Thunderforge yes it was a cartoon. I do not know its origin, I watched it dubbed to my language in a local kids tv station.

Comment: Which language? Which local kid's TV station? Information like that could help narrow down the possible shows.